# Is it possible to negate a regular expression search?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm building a lexical analysis engine in c#. For the most part it is done and works quite well. One of the features of my lexer is that it allows any user to input their own regular expressions. This allows the engine to lex all sort of fun and interesting things and output a tokenised file.

One of the issues im having is I want the user to have everything contained in this tokenised file. I.E the parts they are looking for and the parts they are not (Partial Highlighting would be a good example of this).

Based on the way my lexer highlights I found the best way to do this would be to negate the regular expressions given by the user.

So if the user wanted to lex a string for every occurrence of "T" the negated version would find everything except "T".

Now the above is easy to do but what if a user supplies 8 different expressions of a complex nature, is there a way to put all these expressions into one and negate the lot?

Comment: This would be an example of the regex's that would be used, (?<FindSpaces>\s+) each can only have one named reference.

Comment: When is something considered a token? For example take the string `"aaa bbb ccc"` and the regex `"a{2}|b{3}"`, the token `"bbb"` should probably be ignored, but what about `"aaa"`? An extensive concrete example would help: right now, your question leaves too much open to speculation.

Comment: Think of it in these terms,

You use the lexer to highlight c# code, so you develop say 10 regular expressions that highlight different parts of code. That would leave you with parts that may not need to be highlighted or parts you intentionally did not want to highlight.

Now the engine produces a token file containing the whole string, the part that is tokenised and the part that isn't this means you do not need to know the strings original construction you can just parse the file safe in the knowledge that the parts needing parsing will parse the others wont and it will look correct.

Comment: Sorry, if you can't produce a concrete example, I can't help.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with, a token is the output of a regular expression so if you had a regex that looked for "goat" goat would become a token. Now if you had a sentence, "I like the goat" the word goat would still be a token, but everything else is not. Why is goat a token, because the user of my lexer made it so, what is or is not a token is not relevent per se as its up to the user, I am looking for a way to take whatever regex the user inputs and negate them to find out what they missed so I can include it in the token file.

Comment: The reason i need to find this information is so that I can "complete" the string. If you lexed the word goat using a lexer you would expect to find the word got with some meta data as well as the other string data with no meta data in the same file, it would not make sense to lex and provide only partial data. Is this more clear?

Comment: I'm having trouble with the fact you cannot produce a concrete example of what it is you're trying to do. I thought that was obvious.
It is my experience that people posting regular expression questions tend to overlook many corner cases of the problem they're trying to tackle. When provided an answer, the "but I forgot this" tend to trickle in. That's why I frequently ask for concrete examples. If you can't produce it, no problem, but I'm not going to spend time on it. I'm not going to put in more effort in my answer than you're willing to put into formulating your question. Sorry if ...

Comment: ... I sound harsh (I've hit the character limit of a comment, that's why it's broken into two parts).

Comment: I'm still not sure what answer you are looking for? I have given you multiple answers. Ok, I made a lexer that can fully lex or partially lex. The difference is in how "encompassing" the provided regexp are. These are up to third parties to make. The lexer uses a given set or regexp to lex a string. If the string is not fully lexed I need a way to retrieved the data missed. I presumed negating the regex would suffice IE that would get everything NOT found by someone else's regexp. I am trying to preserve the original data inputed in the tokenised file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine several RegEx's into 1 by using (pattern1)|(pattern1)|...
To negate it you just check for !IsMatch

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("aa bb cc dd", @"(?<token>a{2})|(?<token>d{2})");
```

would return in fact 2 tokens (note that I've used the same name  twice.. that's ok)
Also explore Regex.Split. For instance:

```
var split = Regex.Split("aa bb cc dd", @"(?<token>aa bb)|(?:\s+)");
```

returns the words as tokens, except for "aa bb" which is returned as one token because I defined it as so with (?...).

You can also use the Index and Length properties to calculate the middle parts that have not been recognized by the Regex:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("aa bb cc dd", @"(?<token>a{2})|(?<token>d{2})");
for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
{
   var group = matches[i].Groups["token"];
   Console.WriteLine("Token={0}, Index={1}, Length={2}", group.Value, group.Index, group.Length);
}
```

Comment: Would this work given that I am using named references to pull out details, of complex expressions?

Comment: DeanMc: yes.. it should work. I've added some examples in my response.

Comment: I still don't see how you would negate, for instance you can add match results to a match object but where do you find the others, to add matches to a match object you can use regex.!ismatch()

Comment: I've added another example using Index and Length. Using these two properties you can know if there is a not-matched part of text since the last match. Those will be your "not matched" tokens.

Comment: Aye, that is what I am currently using to pull the text that is missing. I thought if I could negate the expression I could make the code leaner but this seems to be the best way I can get, thanks for your time

Comment: No, if you're not content with the answer(s) provided, there is no need to accept it.